# Hitting Time of Random Walk On A Free Group

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-walk

Consider a free group with generators $a$ and $b$. A word comprises a product of symbols, where a symbol is one of $a$, $b$ or their respective inverses, $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$. We denote $1$ as the empty word. A reduction operation $f$ removes sucessive instances of a symbol and its inverse from a word until no more remain, so $f(1a)=a$ and $f(bb^{-1})=1$. Define $(X_n)$ as follows:

- Sample $\xi_n$ uniformly from $\{a,a^{-1},b,b^{-1}\}$
- Set $X_n=f(X_{n-1},\xi_n)$, i.e we multipltly $\xi_n$ on the right of $X_{n-1}$ and the perform reduction via $f$.

Let $g$ be the function counts the number of symbols in a word. $g(a,a,b)=3$, but $g(1)=0$, i.e. the empty word has $0$ length. Set $Y_n:=g(X_n)$.

Define $T:=\inf\{n\geq1:Y_n=5\}$, the question is how to calculate $\mathbb{P}(X_T=a,a,a,b,b)$ starts form $X_0=1$.

In my opinion, this probability is equal to starts from $X_0=a,a,a,b,b$ then the empty words reoccurs. However, the length of $X_n$ should not exceed $5$. So how can I take care of this boundary condition?

Comment: From length 0, with probability 1 the length grows by 1. From any other length, it increases by 1 with probability 3/4 and decreases by 1 with probability 1/4. This is enough to solve you problem.

Comment: I know what you mean. Actually this method can calculate the probabiltiy that X_n goes to empty words. However, my question is start from 0 but the length do not exceed 5, this probability should less than that from length 5 reach empty word.

Comment: You're right, didn't read the question carefully. Intuitively, the distribution of all resulting 5-letter words is uniform, so we should just count their number.

Comment: That said, the answer should be $1/(4\cdot 3^4)$.

Comment: Intuitively that is correct, I shall do some rigorous proof on this. Thanks for your help~